# Is it possible to have only one ingress routing traffic to different services on different namespaces on GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I would like to know if it's possible to create a single ingress and use it to route traffic to all the services I want, which are deployed on different namespaces on a GKE cluster.

Comment: Hi, I tried creating a single ingress to route traffic to other services in different namespaces on GKE, which didn’t work. However, I found some posts on Kubernetes github found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/17088), which covers a few workarounds as well as some in-depth discussion on the topic.I think you will likely find much of the information there useful.

Answer (score 0):

I use traefik to get this wrokflow, traefik is exposed to internet with a single public IP, then with rules I direct each domain to the correct service